# MuleSoft Database Connector Insert Nested Array

Tags: mysql, database, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a object which has nested arrays and i need to insert that payload into json . Can anyone help me with this

Here is the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `sys`.`order` (`po_date`, `company_name`, `buyer_name`, `buyer_phone`, `company_address`, `company_city`, `company_state`, `company_postal_code`, `shipment_address`, `shipment_city`, `shipment_state`, `shipment_postal_code`, `po_number`) 
    VALUES (:po_date, :company_name, :buyer_name, :buyer_phone, :company_address, :company_city, :company_state, :company_postal_code, :shipment_address, :shipment_city, :shipment_state, :shipment_postal_code, :po_number);
INSERT INTO `sys`.`item` (`name`, `price`, `quantity`, `item_number`) 
    VALUES (:item_name, :item_price, :item_quantity, :item_number);
INSERT INTO `sys`.`order_item` ( `order_ref`, `item_ref`) 
    VALUES ( :order_ref, :item_ref);
```

and here is the input that im sending to database.

```
{
  "po_date": "2/5/2020",
  "company_name": "McCullough, Howe and Graham",
  "buyer_name": "Jeno MacCracken",
  "buyer_phone": "518-508-5392",
  "shipment_postal_code": "12237",
  "po_number": "16-492-5465",
  "items": [
    {
      "item_name": "43-583-0978",
      "item_price": "Sodium Chloride",
      "item_quantity": "26",
      "item_number": "802.41"
    },
    {
      "item_name": "71-788-5293",
      "item_price": "Ciprofloxacin",
      "item_quantity": "100",
      "item_number": "608.64"
    }
  ],
  "order_items": [
    {
      "order_ref": null,
      "item_ref": "43-583-0978"
    },
    {
      "order_ref": null,
      "item_ref": "71-788-5293"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you but I need mode details. Is it Mule 4 or Mule 3? Where are missing parameters like company_address?

In general in Mule 4 you should create Insert statements which look like this:

```
<db:insert doc:name="Insert" doc:id="639efcf2-6422-41c7-b533-b558179efeb9" config-ref="Database_Config">
    <db:sql >INSERT INTO `sys`.`order` (`po_date`, `company_name`, `buyer_name`, `buyer_phone`, `company_address`, `company_city`, `company_state`, `company_postal_code`, `shipment_address`, `shipment_city`, `shipment_state`, `shipment_postal_code`, `po_number`)
```

VALUES (:po_date, :company_name, :buyer_name, :buyer_phone, :company_address, :company_city, :company_state, :company_postal_code, :shipment_address, :shipment_city, :shipment_state, :shipment_postal_code, :po_number)

where you provide Insert SQL and parameters below in separate window 
[image]

That's for first statement which is alone.
For two other statements you do the same but as Bulk Insert where SQLs look similar to yours but inputs are arrays from your payload

[image]

whole flow should look like this
[image]

Actually I do not see how these 3 SQLs are connected. I would expect some usage of general data (like shipment_postal_code) saved for each order. But it is not in your SQLs.

It would be easy to do by merging array items as described here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/MergeArraysItems.html and then using array of these merged items to insert items to the database.

Comment: Hello @alex , Thanks for responding back. I'm using Mule 4. Sorry for not being clear in my question. But here we go:

I have 3 Tables: Order, Item, Order_Item. po_number(order),item_number(item) are foreign keys in order_item table.

what I'm trying to do here is i want all those inserts to be done using one Database Connector (I included all the 3 sql statments for that). I can do it one after the other (insert order, insert item and then relate order_item). But trying to do all using one Connector. Not sure If its possible .

Comment: Sure it is p[ossible. Insert first, grab new primary key by another sql, insert bulk insert with this primary key. Everything as usual. There is no magic here. You can enhance array of items to insert with this just obtained primary key with technique described  at https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/MergeArraysItems.html